# What are the parameters are used in add_action and filters?

Tags: functions, parameter

```
add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

I am unenable to understand what the code is used for?
What are the inbuilt parameters and functions are mostly used in add_action?

Comment: Have you tried to do any research?

Answer (score 1):

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `$hook`
>
> (string) (required) The name of the action to which $function_to_add is hooked. (See  Plugin API/Action Reference for a list of action hooks). Can also be the name of an action   inside a theme or plugin file, or the special tag "all", in which case the function will be called for all hooks)
>
> Default: None
>
> `$function_to_add`
>
> (callback) (required) The name of the function you wish to be hooked. Note: Only string-formatted syntaxes listed in the PHP documentation for the 'callback' type are valid.
>
> Default: None
>
> `$priority`
>
> (int) (optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>
> Default: 10
>
> `$accepted_args`
>
> (int) (optional) The number of arguments the hooked function accepts. In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra arguments that are set when the matching do_action() or apply_filters() call is run. For example, the action comment_id_not_found will pass any functions that hook onto it the ID of the requested comment.
>
> Default: 1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is written on the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

> what are the inbuilt parameters and functions are mostly used in add_action

Not sure what you are asking there, but if you mean how are they used? then take this example.

```
function my_title( $title ) {
    return "A new page title";
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_title', 10, 1 );
```

Somewhere before Wordpress creates the title for a page, it will call `apply_filters('wp_title',$title);`. The above function will hook into that call (meaning it will call your function) then your new function can change it's value.